# Hack to install elementary os apps from loki and - to juno

Tags: appcenter

Is there a "hack" to install all the loki apps I am missing out on juno in the appcenter, by perhaps installing an older version of the appcenter?

Comment: Does that mean you want to install apps from **your previous** elementary installation?

Comment: Could you elaborate on your question, like which app for example?

Comment: maybe like monilet?

Comment: What is that? @javier

Comment: is an example of a loki app. monilet works in loki but don't work in juno. sorry bad english

Comment: Or wammer, or the rest @JavierA.

Answer (score 1):

Your best option is to visit the Github page for each of the apps in question ([Monilet](https://github.com/kmal-kenneth/monilet) for example) and follow the [build instructions](https://github.com/kmal-kenneth/monilet#building-and-installation) on the page.

This may not work for all apps as Juno has a lot of newer packages that may produce incompatibilities, but it will often work, especially for simpler apps.

If you try this and experience any issues, feel free to comment on my answer and I'll try and help if possible.